# Return to last fragment through ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

There are 3 tabs in my ActionBar which for 3 different fragments: Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment 3. There is a ListView in Fragment2 which will start a new activity when a row in the list view is clicked. I've add the following in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

But this will return to the Fragment1 instead of the Fragment2 when I click the back button in ActionBar because Fragment1 is the first fragment in my MainActivity. Can anybody advise how I can return to Fragment2 instead of Fragment1? Thanks

Comment: You want to return to `MainActivity` and highlight `Fragment2`? If so, you're not clear enough with your question and question title ...

Comment: Yes, that what I want to do. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity I suppose you're initializing the tabs in `onCreate` with something like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //or getSupportActionBar() for app.compat.v7
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab1));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab2));
```

and whatever else you need to set it up. Start `DetailsActivity` with [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) by passing the `Intent` that you're currently building and a request code. Something like:

```
protected void startDetailsActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}
```

Then when `MainActivity` pops back in, override `onActivityResult` and if the `requestCode` is the one you've used to start `DetailsActivity` set the current tab position to 1:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 100) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
        // or for compat: getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But mine case is a bit different. For example, there are 3 fragments (Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3 )in my MainActivity. There is a list view in Fragment2. The DetailActivity will be shown when I click list item inside Fragment2. There will be a back button in the DetailActivity. When I click back. it will return to Fragment1 instead of Fragment2 because Fragment1 is the first fragment in MainActivty. And I'll only get the onActivityResult callback inside Fragment2 if I use your method. What your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: `onActivityResult` should be put in `MainActivity` not in the fragment

Comment: Let me have a try. Thanks

Comment: @bagusflyer: any luck?